# Modifying XML with ElementTree: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The following code gives the error:
line 19, in modifyXML
    self.PreFlopCallPower.text = 'NEW VALUE'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

The problem seems to be that self.PreFlopCallPower is only a string and not an elementTree object, even though my example is very similar to the example given on the python etree documentation: self.PreFlopCallPower = entry.find('PreFlopCallPower').text. How can I fix this? I can't see what I'm doing different to the update example listed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml


class XMLHandler(object):
    def __init__(self,StrategyName):
        self.readXML(StrategyName)
        self.modifyXML()

    def readXML(self, StrategyName):
        self.Template = StrategyName
        self.tree = xml.parse('strategies.xml')
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()

        for entry in self.root.findall('Strategy'):
            if entry.get('name') == StrategyName:
                self.PreFlopCallPower = entry.find('PreFlopCallPower').text

    def modifyXML (self):
        self.PreFlopCallPower.text = 'NEW VALUE' # ---ERROR OCCURS HERE---
        self.PreFlopCallPower.set('updated', 'yes')
        self.tree.write('output.xml')


X=XMLHandler('Strategy305PP')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you're storing the *text* of the node (hence have a `str`):

```
self.PreFlopCallPower = entry.find('PreFlopCallPower').text
```

Drop the `.text` to store the *node* itself:

```
self.PreFlopCallPower = entry.find('PreFlopCallPower')
```